# Array of objects, sum by key but the key is unkown

Tags: javascript, arrays

For instance the array:

```
var arr = [
 {
  Test 0: 142.0465973851827,
  Test 1: 199,
  timestamp: "2017-01-16T00:00:00.000Z"
 },
 {
  Test 0: 142.0465973851827,
  Test 1: 199,
  timestamp: "2017-01-17T00:00:00.000Z"
 }
]
```

`Test 0` and `Test 1` can be anything. and I try to return such result:

```
var arr = [
 {
  total: 341,
  timestamp: '2017-01-16T00:00:00.000Z'
 },
 {
  total: 341,
  timestamp: '2017-01-17T00:00:00.000'
 }
]
```

What would be the proper loop type to do it?

Comment: Is there any logic to calculate in the result "*total: 341*". is it the SUM of all Test0+Test1 ?

Comment: @AlaEddineJEBALI It's a sum of everything except timestamp..

Comment: see my answer if it helps you. you can make *exclude* an array of element to exculde and use *if(exclude.indexOf(key) === -1)* to check before updating the *sum* variable

Comment: What did you try so far ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map over the array, then run reduce on the Object.keys of each object, excluding the timestamp property

```js
var arr = [{
  Test0: 142.0465973851827,
  Test1: 199,
  timestamp: "2017-01-16T00:00:00.000Z"
}, {
  Test0: 142.0465973851827,
  Test1: 199,
  timestamp: "2017-01-17T00:00:00.000Z"
}]

var res = arr.map(v => ({
    total: Object.keys(v).reduce((a, b) => b !== 'timestamp' ? a + v[b] : a, 0),
    timestamp: v.timestamp    
}));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

A combination of `array.map`, `Object.keys`, `array.filter`, and `array.reduce` can do this. Use `array.map` to run through the array, `Object.keys` to get the keys of each object and `array.filter` to only grab the keys starting with "Test", then accumulate results using `array.reduce`.

All of the above can easily be done using simple loops as well. The array methods can be done using a regular `for` loop, while `Object.keys` will need a `for-in` guarded with `object.hasOwnProperty`.

Answer (score 0):

```
arr=arr.map(el=>{return el.total=Object.keys(el).filter(key=>key.split("Test")[1]).reduce((total,key)=>total+el[key],0),el;});
```

it does exactly what joseph the dreamer described in the first part of his answer.

Comment: Please edit your answer, or you could be down-voted. As it is now, it's just a suggestion with no context. Please see here for [How to Write a Good Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
function number(v){ return +v || 0; }

arr.map(function(obj){
    var timestamp = obj.timestamp;
    var total = Object.keys(obj)
        .reduce(function(sum, key){
            return sum + number( obj[key] );
        }, 0);

    return { total, timestamp }

})
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```js
var arr = [
 {
  Test0: 142.0465973851827,
  Test1: 199,
  timestamp: "2017-01-16T00:00:00.000Z"
 },
 {
  Test0: 142.0465973851827,
  Test1: 199,
  timestamp: "2017-01-17T00:00:00.000Z"
 }
];

var result = [];
var exclude = "timestamp";
arr.forEach(function(elements){
 var sum = 0;
 for(key in elements){
  if(key !== exclude){
   sum += elements[key];
  }
 }
 var newElement = {total: sum.toFixed(2), timestamp: elements.timestamp}
 result.push(newElement);
});

console.info(result);
```